# Time complexity of dependent nested logarithmic loop

Tags: time-complexity

What is the Big-O complexity of the following loop?

```
for (int i=2; i <= n; i=i*2) {
    for (int k=i; k <= n; k=k*2) {
        times++;
    }
}
```

The outer loop is of course logarithmic, but I am not sure on how to deal with the increasing starting condition of the second loop. It looks similar to logarithmic complexity, but how do I get the k=i in there?

Comment: I can't prove this, but my guess is that this would be bounded by `O(lgn*lgn)`, because the inner loop would also scale as `O(lgn)`.

Comment: Yeah I also had this guess, I was just looking for a backup explanation of this.